# Calculating c mature in MATLAB. How can i solve it?

Tags: matlab, math

i have a `x=(t*n) stock return matrix, that n is number of stock in a portfolio and t is time. I want calculate

```
c=M{[x(it)-k(x)][y(it)-k(y)]} 
 where x(it) 
  return of stock i in time t 
  and the median M is taken with respect to the joint CDF of x(t) 
  and y(t), and k(x) and k(y) are the population medians of x(t) and y(t)
```

for example:

```
x=[1 2 3;6 7 5;3 5 6;7 8 9]

x =

 1     2     3
 6     7     5
 3     5     6
 7     8     9

 t=size(x,1) 
 n=size(x,2)
 medianx=median(x)

 medianx =

   4.5000    6.0000    5.5000

 q=x-medianx(ones(t,1),:)

  q =

    -3.5000   -4.0000   -2.5000
     1.5000    1.0000   -0.5000
    -1.5000   -1.0000    0.5000
     2.5000    2.0000    3.5000
```

I can do this to here and I don't know how can i reach c matrix in matlab. I calculate c manually that:

```
c =

   4.2500    3.2500    4.0000
   3.2500    2.5000    3.2500
   4.0000    3.2500    3.2500
```

where

```
  c(11)=median of(column1*colum1 of matrix q)=4.25
  c(22)=median of(column2*colum2 of matrix q)=2.5
  c(33)=median of(column3*colum3 of matrix q)=3.25
  c(12) & c(21)=median of(column1*column2 of matrix q)=3.25
  c(13) & c(31)=median of(column1*column3 of matrix q)=4
  c(23) & c(32)=median of(column2*column3 of matrix q)=3.25
```

notice that i have a t*n matrix and matrix x  just is a example. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate `c` from `q` using this:

```
c=zeros(3,3);  %Pre-allocation
for m=1:3
   for n=1:3
       c(m,n)= median(q(:,m).*q(:,n));
   end
end
```